# Check where the event is coming from

Tags: c#, event-handling, .net-2.0

I have a external device which sends events to the UI and I change UI according to that. Also I can change UI can send data back to the device. The problem is when device sends update I need change the index of the combo box programmatically but when I do that the SelectedIndexChanged event fire's. I only want that event to fire when I changed the ComboBox from UI itself not programmatically.

**Edit**

```
            if (index > 0 && index < cboHeatPoints.Items.Count)
            {
                //cboHeatPoints.SelectedIndex = index;
            }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to programatically change the ComboBox index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SelectionChangeCommitted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted.aspx) instead of `SelectedIndexChanged`.